# What may cause a GeoRequest:Can't connect to source; error in Expression Engine?

Tags: google-maps, mx-google-map

One of the clients the company I work for uses Expression Engine for their custom site. It was built roughly 2+ years before I hired in, and it’s our only EE site. The person who built it left the company a few months ago, and never trained anyone to maintain the site, so fixing/updating the site has been a task for everyone involved.

It turns out they utilize MX Google Map to display locations for the client. The initial location page loads fine, with several locations, and when I navigate to individual locations, those pages load fine. The search_results page, however, throws this error: GeoRequest : Can’t connect to source;

A few things about this situation:

- No one has updated the site in roughly a month.
- Client does not have access to control panel.
- PHP, MySQL and other server settings have not changed.
- The error just appeared this morning…

Long story short, the client is being vocal about wanting a fix asap. Since nothing has changed, site settings or server settings, I can only imagine that it’s a problem with Google’s Map API? Perhaps?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check [next patch for mx google map](http://www.eec.ms/forums/viewthread/748/)

Comment: looks like it is the same request http://www.eec.ms/forums/viewthread/748/